# TINYMCE customize link properties

Tags: tinymce

I am trying to customize the TINYMCE editor in my CMS (Umbraco).
CMS should't matter.

I need to know how to add a link property to my TinyMCE link property list.
I am trying to add the Google Tracking script to a link when a person enters a title to my textbox I have set up in the TinyMCE editor. I have the textbox showing up. But I need to set the property so it shows up when I update the link property.

I know I can add the Google Tracking script manually, but this option is not user friendly for people who do no know HTML. Trying to make this user friendly, I need to add the property when the link gets added to the content.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You may change properties (example here changes the setting `paste_remove_styles`)

```
editor.settings.paste_remove_styles = true,
```

Be aware that changing these settings won't work if that setting get red only when initializing tinymce (i.e. `cleanup`, `content_css`, `editor_css`,...)!

If this does not help you further please provide some more code, so that we can examine your problem deeper.